# hey! I can't add platform to cordova with `cordova platform add android` and also installing plugins, they used to be working successfully

Tags: reactjs, cordova, npm, cordova-plugins

cordova version 10.0.0
Node version 16.13.1
npm version 8.1.2

I'm using cordova platform add android and the result in console is

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^8.1.0
Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@^8.1.0
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
CordovaError: Error: Cannot find module 'cordova-android/package.json' from '/PROJECTS/apps/mobile-app/cordova'
```

I also used other versions of android platform version like @9.1.0 but the result is the same .

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem?